# Windows 7 No Longer Sees SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have been using an Intel 335 240GB SSD for about a year. Every now and then, when I turn on my computer, the computer says it cannot detect my boot media. I assume my cable was loose so I would open my case up and re-plug my SATA cables. I would re-boot my computer, and would load Windows normally.

Earlier this morning, I received the same error. I have ensured that my SATA cables are connected snug. When I check the BIOS, it still says that the computer is still booting from DVD as first, and SSD as second. I burned AVG Rescue Disc and tried to boot from it. AVG does not see my SSD, but sees my other two 7200 mechanical hard drives. When I insert a Windows 7 boot DVD and try to install a new partition, the boot disc does not display the SSD as one of the available drives. I have just installed Windows 7 onto my second mechanical hard drive (which I use to mirror my data), and I still have the SSD plugged into my machine. When I go into the Device Manager, I see my two mechanical hard drives, but not my SSD.

Just to note that I just tried to install a second 7970 for the second time. I picked up a refurbished 7970 on Black Friday but it was a dud card (artifact-ing everywhere). I got a second refurbished 7970 last night and went to install it this morning. That is when I noticed that my computer cannot detect my boot media. Since then, I have removed my second 7970 from the computer.

I am wondering if my SSD is dead? Is there anyway for me to verify this? What should my next step be to recover from this incident? In addition, how did this happen? My SSD has been working for over a year now.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like the SSD is dead.

The best way to check this would be to take out of the machine and put it into an external caddy and see if you can access it through that.

If you can, then the next thing to check is that the cables are good - plug them into a know good drive and check you can see that.

This should tell exactly which component has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, when a drive (whether a hard disk or SSD) fails, the disk controller will not attempt to communicate with the computer at all, because the controller must be able to communicate with the media on the drive (disk platters or NAND flash) *before* it can communicate with the computer.  It's possible that the disk controller itself is damaged, or that the firmware or critical data structures inside the SSD are corrupted..

Try installing the SSD onto another system or in a hard drive enclosure.  If that works, the cables or the motherboard SATA connector itself may be bad.  If the problem persists despite checking for these possibilities, you'll need to replace the drive.